# Tags editor design problem in Careers create profile page

Tags: bug, jobs, design

SO careers -> create profile form: (I am using the German translation)

- Both tag fields are not expanding, when they are full. Thus you cannot see what you are typing.
- The lower tag field has no headline (maybe this is only a problem in the German translation)

I confirmed this using latest Firefox in Mac OS X with no plugins active.

**edit:**

- Safari works better
- even Internet Explorer 11 works (a little) better than Firefox (see screenshot 4)
- But i thought it should work like in stackoverflow.com/users/preferences ? (see screenshot 3)

**screenshot 1 - Mac OS X using Firefox**
[image: an almost full tag field (before selecting "multithreading")]

**screenshot 2 - Mac OS X using Firefox**
[image: an overfull tag field (after selecting "multithreading")]

**screenshot 3 - Mac OS X using Firefox -> stackoverflow.com/users/preferences...**
*what I though it should look like, because that is easy / non confusing to use*
[image: what i think is easy to use]

**screenshot 4 - Win 7 using Internet Explorer 11**
[image]

Comment: Can you try with other browsers, to see if it's a firefox-only bug?